# Can the 'new' keyword be used on a trait?

Tags: scala

For instance: `implicit val IntOrd = new Ord [Int ] {...}`

Would this code be legal if `Ord` was a trait? I saw this in a document on the differences between OO classes and type classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can easily test this in REPL:

```
scala> trait Ord
defined trait Ord

scala> val x = new Ord {}
x: Ord = $anon$1@32a933c3
```

This is possible because using `new Ord {}` you are not creating an instance of the trait, but an instance of an [anonymous subclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) of the trait. (The linked explanation is for Java, but it works the same way in Scala).

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that if the trait *does* have abstract members, you have to implement them.